# How to set default delivery mode for Google Group(s)

Tags: google-groups

I moderate a google group.  People interested in the group sometimes request a subscription.  When I go to the web approval interface, I am not offered a choice of delivery mode for the member.  After I approve the member, I go to the list of members and check what delivery mode was assigned.  It varies.  I don't see any way of choosing a setting to control this.

Nor do I see any way of choosing a setting in *my own* google account to control the default delivery mode for future requests I might make for joining groups.

---

Edit: here are the four delivery types:

[image]

Is there a die being tossed behind the scenes?

Comment: delivery as in the "group type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to set default delivery email settings for users that request to join the group, but there is a setting for members added directly

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!managemembers/groupname/add

Note: replace groupname by the actual name of your group.

[image: Direct add members]